# How does force of gravity and centripetal force work at the top of a loop?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, reference-frames, free-body-diagram, centripetal-force

I learned that a rollercoaster needs to counteract the effect of gravity by using centripetal force. If the centripetal force is always pointing inwards, toward the centre, how does it counteract gravity when gravity is pointing in the same direction as it.

Comment: As Floris pointed out centrifugal force is a pseudo force. 
[Here](https://youtu.be/nh26C519wuo) is a video link for a deeper insight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a misconception here.

The centripetal force is the force needed to make an object move in a circular path - or put differently, for the object to accelerate in a direction perpendicular to its motion.

When, for example, you swing a ball on a string in a circle, you provide that force through the tension in the string.

A car on a rollercoaster feels a force from gravity, and another force from the rails. When you are at the top of the curve, these two forces push in the same direction - and this means you will either:

1. have less force from the rails (to the point where sometimes you are actually "hanging" from the rails - the wheels on a roller coaster grab from both the top and the bottom)
2. go around a much tighter loop (also because you are typically going slower, you need the loop to be even tighter).

People are sometimes scared of the "virtual twin" of the centripetal force: the fictitious centrifugal force (which is very real in a rotating frame of reference). If you need the car to be kept on the rails by its motion at the top, it is sufficient that the centrifugal force ($F_c$, force pushing outwards) is greater than the force of gravity ($F_g$, pointing inwards). The net result will be an inward force by the rails ($F_r$); added to the force of gravity, this will keep the car on the rails.

[image]

Comment: +1       admit it, do you close your eyes on the climb up and the first drop, after that, no problem???

Comment: @CountTo10 - I avoid roller coasters if at all possible. They (the vibrations, mostly) give me a headache.

Comment: Picture yourself sitting on a scale while riding and what that scale will read at the top of the loop and then the bottom and it might be easier to picture.